# GetCurrentProcessId() vs System.Diagnostics.Process.Id - discrepancy in return type

Tags: .net, windows, api, process

I've never noticed it before, but apparently the datatype to represent id of a process differs from native Windows API and and .NET's `Process.Id`.  Specifically, [`GetCurrentProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx) is defined as

```
DWORD WINAPI GetCurrentProcessId(void);
```

... and `DWORD`, of course is defind as `unsigned long`.  .NET's [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Id`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id(v=vs.110).aspx) is defined as

```
public int Id { get; }
```

... with `int` of course being a signed value.

Since the ultimate source of the value is the Windows kernel, and the value would expected to be the same as seen either via Windows API call, or via .NET's native `Process.Id`, how come the data types returned by the two differ?

I understand that because Windows kernel tries to keep process ids at the lower end of spectrum (for non-technical reasons), and even the most beefiest of the machines wouldn't have resources to host enough processes to push the upper limits of signed integer.  But that still doesn't seem to justify creating type mismatch.

So why the discrepancy?  Should interop be used to get process id and avoid using .NET's way of getting the id?

Comment: It is this way through-out the .NET Framework, essential 15 years ago to get [CLSCompliant(true)] framework code.  Unsigned value types were a problem, neither VB.NET nor JScript supported them.  And still the case for the many other languages that integrate with the framework.   It does not matter, you never do math on a process id.

Comment: @HansPassant, ah, I thought it was VB limitation related, but the "never do math" is the light-bulb moment for me.  That makes total sense - thanks!